# Android: phonegap/cordova: switch full screen mode while app is running

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to switch between full screen mode and normal mode while my app is running.

is there any phonegap plugin to do this for me (Android) ?

if no, Please tell me how can I switch between full screen and normal in java, called in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do using this plugin: https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen

it has functions AndroidFullScreen.showSystemUI, AndroidFullScreen.leanMode, AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode to do the switch.

Comment: :D thanks a lot ...
however, I'm using ionic framework now...
still it might come handy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method. It displays full screen.

Set Fullscreen as following method.

call this method before "super.LoadURL("....");"

```
    //Fullscreen (No title bar and status bar) 
    public void setFullscreen() {  
         getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);  //Clean FLAG  
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    }
```

Clean `FLAG "FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN".`
 This is supported by DroidGap.

Comment: No, I mean to go full screen for some pages and return to normal when page is closed

Comment: @Aravin Is your answer for immersve mode using cordova? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html