# Phonegap full screen app

Tags: android, xml, cordova, config

I have made an app using PhoneGap. I need to hide the menu and action bar but the code is not working the way I have it now. Below is the little config.xml to get full screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget id="com.bensishop.bensishopapp" version="0.0.1">
    <name>BensiShop</name>
    <description>
        Bensishop app
    </description>
    <author email="info@bensishop.com" href="http://www.bensishop.com">
        Bensishop
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
   <platform name="android">
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
   </platform>
</widget>
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to add?
Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981459/android-phonegap-cordova-switch-full-screen-mode-while-app-is-running/22981544#22981544

Comment: It needs a few more steps, I posted my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302251/making-an-android-app-fullscreen-with-cordova/28582939#28582939

Answer (score 1):

Open the project built by phonegap and edit the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Put this in all Activity :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: where do i find the AndroidManifest.xml file, im new to phonegap

Comment: PhoneGap has built a native Android Project somewhere. Find it, and open it with Eclpis (plugin Android) and modify the AndroidManifest.xml  file. Them, rebuilt with Eclipse. Or developp directly in native Android ?

Comment: im going to try it with eclipse.. so i need to open the apk in exlipse and edit the manifest.xml, right?

Comment: It's not an .apk. APK is like .exe in windows. You have to open the project. It's a folder with other folder inside like "src", "res,"asset","gen" and some other files, and a bin folder where you can find your .apk

Comment: I get the apk part but where do i find this project i dont have that folder with other folders inside.. thanks btw

Comment: I don't know, maybe in your cordova/phonegap project. What are your folders in your cordova project/folder ?

Comment: did you find the project ?