# Cordova- how to hide virtual navigation buttons on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to hide in my app virtual navigation button for devices which does not have analog buttons (see image below).

[image]

How can i do it in Cordova (Ionic) please?

Answer (score 2):

I found this cordova plugin [cordova-fullscreen-plugin](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-fullscreen-plugin) can help you.But it only support Android 4.4+.

> // Hide system UI and keep it hidden (Android 4.4+ only)
>   AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode(successFunction, errorFunction);

And your question is duplicate with [Making an Android app fullscreen with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302251/making-an-android-app-fullscreen-with-cordova)