# cordova hybrid app soft nav bar overlapping my menubar on bootom

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap, cordova-plugins

I develope an android app with apache cordova. I'm using angularjs and bootstrap. I have problem with some android devices which have the soft nav bar on the bottom like this.

[image: Soft NavBar Android]

When the soft nav bar is active the user can't see the buttons from the app, becouse the soft nav bar overlapp my button panels.

My code for the footer is similar to this.

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="row" id="bottomNav">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></i><br>Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i><br>Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></i><br>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to move up my navbar, that it will be over the soft nav bar from android? Or how can I check if the soft nav bar is shown?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I have this values in my config.xml file and also not added full screen plugin still this is working for me. So please try this and let me know if this is working or not.

```
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
```

## Updated

Also check try add `toolbar=no` to your inappbrowser link, not sure this will work for android or not but this is working for iOS

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'toolbar=no');
```

Comment: the easiest way would be, if I could check if the soft nav bar is shown, and then find out the height...

Comment: but you have to do this for every different devices, may be you can try using my updated answer. If it will work then you dont need to do anymore changes in your code

Comment: Ohk so if this is for inappbrowser then you have to set `AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode` like [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31272839/3840093) after installing `full-screen-plugin`

Comment: ok and do you know where I have to set this AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode?

Comment: It's not really working. When the app starts this soft nav bar is hidden, but when I do something in the app, it appears again and covers my button bar....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130573/discussion-between-kirankumar-dafda-and-user1861065).

Comment: Try using viewport-fit: https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/